# C : Is this array initialization legal?

Tags: c

```
int ar[] = { 1, 2, 3, };
```

Is this code legal?

(My intention is that)

```
int ar[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Comment: Define `legal`. What does your compiler say?

Comment: I assume you're worried about the trailing comma in the first initializer list?

Comment: I honestly wonder what is your research and effort you put into this.

Comment: For which edition of the C standard?

Comment: @KeithThompson The optional trailing comma is in the syntax for [at least since 1985](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html#initializer).

Comment: @reto My compiler (gcc 4.8.2 with `-std=c99`) says 'ok', But I wonder whether it is legal.

Comment: @halex It was in PWB Unix, 1977.

Comment: There isn't much that gcc -std=c99 accepts that isn't legal, but if you're worried you can add -ansi -pedantic.

Comment: @JimBalter -ansi is the same thing as -std=c89, so you shouldn't use that. Correct compiler options would be: `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall` (or c11 if supported).

Comment: @Lundin: Or you can use `-std=c89`, `-std=c90`, or `-ansi` (all equivalent) if you want to enforce C90 rules; even now, not all compilers support C99.

Comment: @halex: Quite right. C99 added trailing commas for `enum` declarations, but they've been allowed in initializers since long before that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, stray commas are allowed in initializer lists in both C89 and GNU89. Quite useful in macros that take optional/variadic parameters.

See section 3.5.7 in the [ANSI C standard](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt) for where this is defined.

```
3.5.7 Initialization

Syntax

      initializer:
              assignment-expression
              {  initializer-list } 
              {  initializer-list , }
```

Comment: Why cite a 23 year old, obsolete source?

Comment: It is not obvious, because unlike the current C standard, C89 isn't consistent when it comes to trailing commas. It allows it for arrays, structs, unions, but not for enums. Therefore it is better to forget about C89 and look at C99 or C11.

Comment: @Lundin the trailing comma was allowed for initializer lists, but enums types declarations are not using initializer lists.

Comment: @ouah Yes, but the enum syntax was still inconsistent.

Answer (score 5):

```
int ar[] = { 1, 2, 3, };
```

The above declaration is valid.

See C99, 6.7.8:

> ```
> 6.7.8 Initialization
> Syntax
> 1 initializer:
> assignment-expression
> { initializer-list }
> { initializer-list , }
> ```

The `{ initializer-list , }` line explictly allows the trailing comma in an initializer list.

Comment: 6.7.9 in C11. Also note that trailing comma is allowed in enums, but it wasn't allowed before C99. C99 fixed this and made enums consistent with arrays/structs.