# What is the reason to #define and #undefine a macro in an array initializer?

Tags: c, arrays, macros, initialization, c-preprocessor

I came across this code snippet. What's the purpose of `#define` and `#undef` a macro in an array initializer ?

```
#define MY_ARR MACRO(30)\ 
               MACRO(40) 
int array[] = { 
#define MACRO(a) a, 
                10, 
                20, 
             MY_ARR 
#undef MACRO 
};
```

Comment: Where did you find such stuff? Without more context it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Are you sure there was no use of `MACRO` at all in the code you found?

Comment: Guys, even i felt it's senseless before posting. But, the developer who wrote this code might have something in his mind. So, thought of checking with our community, if they can sense something. Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: @ERROR It's not finished yet! Provide some more information. If possible, cite the source explicitly, so we can take a look at it.

Comment: @ERROR And is the shown snippet exactly equivalent to the source?

Comment: Often these kind of mysteries can be solved by looking at version control history. Perhaps something was removed at some point, and remaining code was left unused.

Comment: Guys, pls accept my apologies.  Here is the equivalent source code.                                                        #define MY_ARR MACRO(30)\                                                                                              MACRO(40)                                                                                                                        int array[] = { 
#define MACRO(a) a,
              10,
              20,                                                                                                                     
          MY_ARR
#undef MACRO
};

Comment: @ERROR those are called X-macros, they're useful **only** if `MY_ARR` is used in **many** places... Also, if the `10, 20,` are on *separate lines* as in your example, it'd be better to just `#define MACRO(a)` just before `MY_ARR` is used.

Answer (score 0):

`MACRO` will only be known between its `#define` and its `#undef`

As `MACRO` is never used within its defined scope, it does nothing, so the result is

```
int array[]= {10, 20,};
```

Comment: some compilers accept the extra "," in the end, though

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I just found out: MS VC2008

Comment: "Note that this has a syntax error because there is a , too many at the end of the initializer list."  That's not a syntax error. C has always allowed trailing comma at the end of an initializer list. C90 didn't allow trailing comma for enums though. This was fixed in C99, making initializer lists and enums consistent. These trailing comma rules are important when writing more obscure stuff like X macros.

Comment: @Lundin, thanks for the explanation. Still sounds as a syntax error to me ("syntax hack")

Comment: Specifically, C11 6.7.9: _initializer:_ ... `{` _initializer-list_  `}` ... `{` _initializer-list_ `, }`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466831/c-is-this-array-initialization-legal/23467102#23467102

Comment: @PaulOgilvie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311864/history-of-trailing-comma-in-programming-language-grammars

Comment: For anyone who is interested in C++ equivalent - This is also the most popular question regarding trailing comma: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043372/int-a-1-2-weird-comma-allowed-any-particular-reason

Comment: question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason, the code is senseless. Since the macro is defined, immediately undefined and never called, this expands to:

```
int array[]= { 10, 20, };
```

Comment: yeah, I know :) old C answer habits die hard

Comment: it has been edited...

Answer (score 0):

This function-like macro definition has no use because it is indeed not used anywhere in the array initializer until its undefinition at the end of the initializer list.

For example Clang complains this too:

> "*warning: macro is not used [-Wunused-macros]*"

As result after the preprocessing, the code is equivalent to:

```
int array[] = { 10, 20, };
```

---

I guess the intention was to define a first element and initialize it with the value of `a` by the use of conditional compilation directives, so that `array` is composed of 3 elements instead of 2, with the first element containing the value of `a`.

This would be more appropriate for this case:

`MACRO` is defined *before* its use/check in the array initializer list. If it was defined, `a` is inserted into the initializer. Since `MACRO` has no further use, we can `#undef` it after the initialization.

```
#define MACRO 
#define a 5

int array[] = { 

    #ifdef MACRO 
        a,
    #endif
    #undef MACRO
        10,        
        20,        
};
```

Note: `a` could also be a `const` qualified integer object than a preprocessor macro: `const int a = 5;`.

Comment: It has been edited...